# Proof verification (complex analysis)

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers

Suppose $|z| = 1$ I proved the following  fact $|\cos(z)| \leq e$, so now I need to show the following $|\int_{\tau}\frac{\cos(z)}{z} dz| \leq 2\pi e$, given that $\tau : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ traces the unit circle.

Proof:

$$\left|\int_{\tau}\frac{\cos(z)}{z} dz\right| \leq \int_{\tau}\left|\frac{\cos(z)}{z} dz\right| \leq \int_{\tau}\frac{|\cos(z)|}{|z|}|dz| \leq e|2\pi*i| = 2\pi *e$$

Comment: $\cos z$ is a complex number. To say $\cos z<e$ is nonsensical.  Did you mean $|\cos z|<e$?  Otherwise, your proof is fine.  What is you question??

Comment: You can compute $\int_\tau { \cos (z) \over z} dz = 2 \pi i$ directly using residues, or power series.

Comment: I didn't learn about residues yet

Comment: and yes I meant to say that |cos(z)| < e

Comment: Use power series.

Comment: Your proof is fine,with the amended statement $    |\cos z|\leq e$. When using LaTeX, you can just leave a space instead of using an asterisk. E,g, 2\pi e with dollar signs ,gives $2\pi e$.

Comment: By the way what is $ \max \{ |\cos z | : |z|=1\}$ ?